# Pause Python script until user clicks on plot twice

Tags: python, events, matplotlib

I'm trying to write a script that saves the coordinates of the first two mouse clicks on a plot (generated via matplotlib), pausing the script until these clicks occur. I tried to implement the "pause" with a while loop, which should finish once the callback function detects that the mouse has been clicked twice. However, once the while loop starts running, clicking on the plot area seems to have no effect. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
coords = []
pause = True

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.pcolormesh(x_grid, y_grid, arr)
plt.show()

def onclick(event):
    global coords
    coords.append((event.xdata, event.ydata))
    if (len(coords)==2):
        pause = False
        fig.canvas.mpl_disconnect(cid)

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)

while pause:
    pass

# ...More code to follow, after the while loop finishes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited Answer:
I would look into something like this, they have a demo app but this seems to be exactly the functionality you want.

https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ginput.html

This would turn your code into:

```
plt.pcolormesh(x_grid, y_grid, arr)
coords = plt.ginput(2, show_clicks=False)
plot.show(block=False)
```

This would return the first two click coords in the window and leave the plot open.

-- Original Answer

Do you care about the plot being open after clicking? If not, then you can remove the while loop because the `plt.show()` function is inherently blocking. New version of code is then:

```
coords = []
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.pcolormesh(x_grid, y_grid,arr)

def onclick(event):
    global coords
    coords.append((event.xdata, event.ydata))
    if (len(coords)==2):
        fig.canvas.mpl_disconnect(cid)
        plt.close()

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
plt.show()
print('Finished')
```

You could always (assuming the plot isn't super long to render) just have a call afterwards like:

```
plt.pcolormesh(x_grid, y_grid, arr)
plt.show(block=False)
```

To generate a non-blocking version of your plot after the clicking process is done. (This seems dumb but I can't seem to find a quick way to convert a blocking figure into a nonblocking figure)

Comment: Andrew, thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately this doesn't quite work, because the code below this block (indicated above with my comment "# ...More code to follow, after the while loop finishes") continues to run with the plot window open. I need the program to pause in order to obtain the mouse coordinates, because those coordinates are needed in the later code. I could also be misunderstanding your suggestion because I'm unclear about what "blocking" means in the context of plt.show(). Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Blocking means once you call `plt.show` it won't execute anything else, it freezes (or blocks) execution until you take the plot down. If you add a print statement into your while loop, it shouldn't print anything because it never actually gets to the while loop as in your current code.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. In that case, I suspect that plt.show() is not blocking correctly, because my program executes the code that follows plt.show().

Comment: If you say, `plt.show()` does not "block correctly", you will probably want to tell us *how* you run the code and give information about the system, since by default it does interrupt the script.

Comment: My apologies for giving insufficient information. I'm running Python 2.7.6 on a MacOS10.2.6 system, using the Enthought Canopy environment. Please let me know which other information would be useful.

Comment: Which part of "Enthought Canopy environment" it are you using to *run* the code?

Comment: Check my updated solution, I would look at https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ginput.html because I think it's close to the functionality you want.

Comment: Andrew, that solution worked, thank you!  Ernest -- unfortunately I must confess that I don't know how to answer your question. I apologize for my ignorance if this is a very basic question. I'm running the code within the Canopy editor window. Since Andrew was able to solve the problem, the point is somewhat moot, but I would be grateful to learn how to answer your question in the future.